# Why is curl returning json while rest-client gem is returning gzip?

Tags: json, http, gzip, rest-client

`curl 'myproject/rest/v1/events?select=*' \ -H "apikey: SUPABASE_KEY" \ -H "Authorization: Bearer SUPABASE_KEY"`

I'm using supabase and it has its own api and the above is the curl command. Sure enough after copy pasting it in my terminal, it returns JSON data (normal behavior).

`res = RestClient.get('myproject/rest/v1/events?select=*', {apikey: supabase_key, Authorization: "Bearer #{supabase_key}"})`

but when im using rest-client gem in ruby, it returns gzip.

is curl receiving gzip but automatically decompressing it?
is there a way to receive JSON using rest-client instead of gzip or automatically decompress it?

i tried net/http and it returns gzip too.

Comment: If the client doesn't pass the header to accept gzip encoding, there is no reason the server would return Gzip-ed data.

Comment: This sounds very like the server is compressing  the content and sending a `content-encoding: gzip` header. `curl` with automatically decompress the payload data.  If you have access to `wireshark` (or an equivalent), try to snooping the connection. For content to be returned compressed, the client should include `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip` and the server responds with a `content-encoding: gzip` header. If the `accept-encoding` header is present that is the root-cause. If your client can disable the `accept-encoding` header, it should prevent the server from returning compressed content.